# How to make a function accept structs that implement generic interfaces?

Tags: go, generics

I have the following generic interface

```
type Worker[input any, output any] interface {
    Process(input) output
}
```

I'm trying to implement the interface with the following

```
type IntWorker[i int, o int] struct{}

func (w *IntWorker[i, o]) Process(input i) o {
    fmt.Println("running i")
    return 1
}
```

When I try to use this I get the following error

```
mgr := internal.NewWorkManager()
iwkr := &IntWorker[int, int]{}
mgr.RegisterWorker(iwkr)


cannot use iwkr (variable of type *IntWorker[int, int]) as internal.Worker[any, any] value in argument to : *IntWorker[int, int] does not implement internal.Worker[any, any] (wrong type for method Process)
        have Process(input int) int
        want Process(any) any
```

Note the last segment, it says want `any` but have `int`.  I'm not sure how to fix this since I was under the impression you can pass anything to `any`

The variable is passed to this function:

```
func (m *WorkManager) RegisterWorker(f Worker[any, any]) uuid.UUID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any functions that should take generic variants of the `Worker` interface must themselves be generic functions.

```golang
func TakesAnyWorker[input any, output any](w Worker[input, output]) { ... }
```

The type `Worker[any, any]` is not a generic type, and is only compatible with values implementing `Process(any) any` as that is what your interface definition dictates.

In your example, the function is a method, which cannot take type parameters in Go 1.19. If a single `WorkManager` will always take `Worker`s of the same type, then you can make the `WorkManager` a congruent generic type like this:

```golang
type WorkManager[input any, output any] struct { ... }

func (m *WorkManager[input, output]) RegisterWorker(f Worker[input, output]) uuid.UUID
```

If your single `WorkManager` needs to take `Worker`s of differing types, then I'm afraid you have bigger problems than generics can solve and you'll be forced to use regular interfaces and `reflect`.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that, I need to support multiple worker types so I guess I will have to revert to using interfaces